# memcpy ing float into int

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I want to know whether we can memcpy a structure containing 2 float variables into another structure containing 2 int variable. This is what I have wriiten so far

```
struct stFloat
{
float a;
float b;
};


struct stInt
{
int a;
int b;
};


int main()
{
struct stFloat aa;
aa.a=12.234;
aa.b=673.797;

struct stInt bb;

memcpy(&bb,&aa,sizeof(stFloat));

printf("%d %d\n",bb.a,bb.b);

return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately I am not getting the desired result. The output that I was expecting is **12 673** but the output looks like some garbage. Can somebody help me resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why were you expecting that result?

Comment: @Oliver I thought only the integer part will get copied.

Comment: `a = b;` is not the same as `memcpy(&a, &b, ...);`.

Comment: @oliver I know but I don't want to individually copy each fields into the struct variable. So is there any other way where I can directly copy all the data in one single line.

Comment: Are you writing C, or are you writing C++? _Pick one_.

Comment: @Lightness actually its kind of both. So I am OK with both C and C++  language solution

Comment: No, you need to pick one for a question on this site. They are two different languages. Tag the language you're _actually_ using. You cannot be using "both" at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer and float have different internal representation, and memcpy is simply a bitwise copy so if you were expecting the numbers to be converted in some way it's not going to happen.

Instead you need to do it yourself, for example by declaring a constructor or function or assignment operator that allows you to assign stfloats to stint. This also allows you to explicitly indicate the conversion you want.

In general it is a bad idea to use memcpy (among other things, because it only works for PODs, and also because you get this sort of problem). It's a C thing that should be avoided in C++.

Comment: @Gujit I don't want to individually copy each fields into the struct variable. So is there any other way where I can directly copy all the data in one single line.

Comment: @Harry: No, as this answer says.

Comment: If you add an assigment operator you can use it to copy all the data in a single line anywhere you like. You just have to spend three (more or less) additional lines defining that assignment operator.

Comment: @Gujit Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, but you can write a function which will do it for you :

```
void cpy(struct stFloat *src, struct stInt *dest){
dest->a = (int)src->a;
dest->b = (int)src->b;
}
```

then, call it by passing your structures by <del>references</del> pointer (else it will only work on copies of the structures) :

```
struct stFloat f;
struct stFloat i;

cpy(&f,&i);
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :  In the function's body yes, but isn't it the right terminology when we pass arguments address with & ?

Comment: Not in C++, no. Best to avoid it in C too (in which it is ambiguous) for that reason.

Comment: @Timtow Thanks for the solution