# Converting void* to int*

Tags: c, types, void-pointers

We have two variables fa and fb of float type. We copy blocks of memory into variables of type void*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float fa = 2.11, fb = 2.2;
    void *a, *b;
    int *ffa, *ffb;

    a = malloc(sizeof(float));
    b = malloc(sizeof(float));
    memcpy(a, &fa, sizeof(float));
    memcpy(b, &fb, sizeof(float));

    ffa = (int*)a;
    ffb = (int*)b;

    printf("ffa = %d\n", *ffa);
    printf("ffb = %d\n", *ffb);

    return 0;
}
```

After converting them to int type, we get huge numbers. Why is this happening?

```
ffa = 1074203197
ffb = 1074580685
```

Comment: `Why is this happening?` Because floats != ints. What exactly did you expect? `After converting them to int type` You're not _converting_ anything, you're interpreting the bits which store a float as integers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [memcpy ing float into int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161100/memcpy-ing-float-into-int)

Comment: Sounds a lot like a teaching assignment...

Comment: "Why is this happening?" is not a valid question. Anything can happen, unless there's a reason to the contrary. Most often these reasons are passages from the language standard that define certain behaviour. Do you have a reason to believe that something different should happen?

Answer (score 2):

> We copy blocks of memory into variables of type void*.

Careful.  You are copying into memory *pointed to by* variables of type `void *`.  But, yes, you are copying *blocks of memory*.  In particular, you are not *assigning values*, and therefore you have no possibility of *converting values*.

> After converting them to int type, we get huge numbers.

Again, you have to be careful with your language.  You did not convert anything to `int` type.  You converted two pointers from `void *` type to `int *` type.  You converted the pointers.  You did *not* convert the pointed-to values!

*If* you had said

```
float fa = 2.11;
int ia = (int)fa;
```

you would have converted the floating-point number 2.11 to the integer 2.  But that's not what you did.

In [IEEE-754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), the number 2.11 is represented by the bit pattern `0x40070a3d`.  (How it is that those crazy-looking bits actually represent the number 2.11 is a fascinating story, but beyond the scope of this answer.)  And the hexadecimal number `0x40070a3d` in decimal is 1074203197, which is precisely the number you saw.

When you say

```
ffa = (int*)a;
```

you are *not* saying, "Hey compiler, those bits representing the floating-point number 2.11, I want you to convert them to an integer for me."  (Again, to do that, you'd want `int ia = (int)fa;`.)  No, what this line says is "Hey, compiler, that pointer `a` pointing to some bits representing a floating-point number, I want to pretend they're a pointer pointing to an integer."

In other words, you did not change the pointed-to bits.  And, in a way, you didn't change the pointer, either: `ffa` points to the exact same spot in memory that `a` does.  But what you very importantly changed was the *interpretation* of the pointed-to bits.  `a` is a pointer to a spot in memory where we expect there to be a value of type `float`, while `ffa` is a pointer to a spot in memory where we expect there to be a value of type `int`.

So if you say

```
printf("%f\n", *a);
```

you have a pointer, `a`, which is assumed to point to a `float`, and you use `*` to "take the contents of" the pointer, so you fetch the pointed-to value, and print it using `%f`, and you see `2.11`.

But when you say

```
printf("ffa = %d\n", *ffa);
```

you have a pointer, `ffa`, which is assumed to point to an `int`, and you use `*` to "take the contents of" the pointer, so you fetch the pointed-to value, and print it using `%d`, and you see `1074203197`.

You have used pointers to take the same bit pattern, sitting in the same spot in memory, and interpret it in two different ways.
Interpreted as type `float`, the bit pattern `0x40070a3d` is 2.11.
Interpreted as type `int`, the bit pattern `0x40070a3d` is 1074203197.

This is a common (and powerful) use of pointers, although now that you're starting to understand it, I have to leave you with some cautions.  Taking bit patterns in memory and reinterpreting them as different types, as we've been doing here, is actually a little more complicated than this question has made it look.  In practice, there are two real-world complications that come into play, [*alignment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875369/what-is-data-alignment-why-and-when-should-i-be-worried-when-typecasting-pointe) and [*strict aliasing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  At some point you may want to learn more about those.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because floats are not integers and are saved differently in memory. Ints use methods like 2's or 1's complement while floats use methods like IEE.

Comment: Yep you are right ,my bad.